# Python Flask - Does not return output if the file extension is xls

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a small Flask project that gets some inputs from the user and extracts some data from the database based on the input back to the user and returns an output file.

The code works just fine if the file format is csv. However when the file format is xls, I see the output being generated but the flask app does not return the file.

Edited:

Given below is the code for **views.py**

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['GET','POST'])
def data():
    form = DataForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        start_date = form.start_date_field.data
        end_date = form.end_date_field.data
        file_extension = form.file_extension_field.data

        rep_func(name=name, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, exten=file_extension)

        current_directory = path.abspath(path.join(__file__, ".."))
        base = os.path.join(current_directory, 'files')

        if file_extension == 'csv':
            data = pd.read_csv(base + f'/final_output/{name}_{end_date}.{file_extension}', sep=r',(?!\s|\Z)', engine='python') 
            resp = make_response(data.to_csv(index=False))
            resp.headers["Content-Disposition"] = f'attachment; filename={name}_{end_date}.{file_extension}'
            resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"
        elif file_extension == 'xls':
            data = pd.read_excel(base + f'/final_output/{name}_{end_date}.{file_extension}')
            resp = make_response(data.to_excel(index=False))
            resp.headers["Content-Disposition"] = f'attachment; filename={name}_{end_date}.{file_extension}'
            resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
            return resp

    return render_template('file.html', form=form)
```

Could anyone advise on where am I going wrong with this. Thanks

Comment: Err... comparing against `csv:` and `xls:` doesn't look right (what's with the `:` in there)... Also - are you sure the extension isn't `xlsx` instead of `xls` ?

Comment: @JonClements, I am trying to cater to both formats (xls and xlsx) but wanted to address one format at a time.

Comment: Also `resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "xls"` isn't the correct content-type for an excel file... I *think* the generic one I've used before is `'application/vnd.ms-excel'`

Comment: Another note... you use `{permalink}` in your headers... where's that ever set? Are you sure you're not getting a `NameError` exception there?

Comment: @JonClements, sorry I mis-typed that.. The other issue I am encountering is the below:

  resp = make_response(loads.to_excel(index=False))


TypeError: to_excel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'excel_writer'

Could you please advice..

Comment: It's as it says... you need to give it somewhere to *write to*... whether that's a file or a `BytesIO` object you can then include in the response...

Comment: @JonClements, could be assist on how this could be done. I thought the line above where we define "data" has the path where the file gets saved to